# Parsing a JArray object in C#

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a JArray object named as `response` whose value is:

```
{[
  {"alternatives": [
      {
       "transcript": "some text",
       "confidence": 0.77053386
      }
    ]
  },
  {"alternatives": [
      {
       "transcript": " some other text",
       "confidence": 0.84036005
      }
    ]
  }
]}
```

I'm trying to access the `transcript` values and concatenate them together. This is my code:

```
 var results = response.ToObject<IList<Alternatives>>();
 string mostConfidentTranscript = "";
 foreach (var r in results)
      mostConfidentTranscript += r.transcript + "\n";
```

Where `Alternatives` class is defined as:

```
public class Alternatives
{
    public double confidence { get; set; }
    public string transcript { get; set; }
}
```

The code compiles with no errors, however, `results` is an empty list. What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You appear to have multiple objects each of which *contains* an array with a single `Alternatives`. That's a very odd JSON structure... is that part fixed? What is generating the JSON?

Comment: @JonSkeet it's the response of a http post request and I can't really change it.

Comment: Looking at it again, the JSON you've posted is invalid. It's not a valid array, because it's wrapped in `{ }`. It's not a valid object, because immediately inside the `{` is a value (the array) rather than a property name. Is that really the exact JSON you receive?

Comment: That JSON is invalid.  If you upload to http://jsonlint.com/ you will see an error that `{[` is not valid.  A `{` indicates the beginning of an *object*, which is an unordered set of name/value pairs.  But the `[` indicates the beginning of an array, which is a value; there should be a property name first.  See http://www.json.org/ for a description of the JSON standard, which is very simple.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll find a way to turn it into json first

Comment: it's better to use JSON.net to Deserialize it first and do more what you want

Answer (score 1):

payload is not right, if you mean post a list of object, better to change to:

```
{"value":[...]}
```

then you can read this as a JObject, and get the value as JArray.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JObject>().Result;
var results = result["value"] as JArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON provided isn't valid. A little modification , and this is what worked for me -

```
public class Alternative
{
    public double confidence { get; set; }
    public string transcript { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject{
    public List<Alternative> Alternatives{get;set;}
}

var json = "[{'alternatives':[{'transcript':'some text','confidence':0.77053386}]},{'alternatives':[{'transcript':' some other text','confidence':0.84036005}]}]";
var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
// output : "some text: some other text"
Console.WriteLine(res[0].Alternatives[0].transcript + ":" + res[1].Alternatives[0].transcript);
```